# logging into a website

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, autologin

I'm having some problems logging into a certain website, using python. I'm using the post method but I think that my parameters for the form are not right. This is my fist time trying things like this so maybe i'm doing it completely wrong, any kind of help is welcome.

This is what i got from the website:

```
 <form method="post" action="/auth/login" id="login-form"  novalidate>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="4d1964264067f1789bcbb7b01ca3f8366864ee7c" />


        <div class="form-item text username">
            <label>Gebruikersnaam</label>
            <span><input type="email" name="username" autofocus /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item text password">
            <label>Wachtwoord</label>
            <span><input type="password" name="password" /></span>
```

And this is my code,

```
import requests
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'aurl.com'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
htmltext = br.open(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,"html.parser")
zoek = soup.findAll('input',attrs={'name':'_token'})
zoektekst = zoek[0]["value"]

print _token

Payload = {'password':'??','_token':_token,'username':'??@gmail.com'}
print Payload
r = requests.post("theurl.com",data=Payload)
print r.text
```

Comment: Use google chrome developer tools network tab to see what a correct login should look like. Then replicate it in your python.

Comment: @RPGillespie what do i have to get from the network tab, only the form data? because thats already there.... but i have noticed that the payload maby isn't in the correct order i think its have to be username, password, _token (i know it is not in the right order above, but thats because i have been playing around with it to get it right)... if i run my code it automatically puts it in a wrong order, is there any way to fix that? thanx

Comment: Is your POST url correct? The network tab will show you the correct URL to POST to.

Comment: Also, what type is the payload - JSON, NVP, etc.? Network tab will also show you the payload format.

Comment: @RPGillespie under which header is the "type" defined?

Comment: `Content-Type` in the Request will tell you what kind of payload generally, but you can click `view source` on the `Form Data` section to see *exactly* how it is being sent over the wire

Comment: i just found the content type which is: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 1):

I've checked Your code, and seems to be working correctly. Yet without url and error message i don't think anyone can answer your question why it does not work.

Wild guess for now - form posts data to url/auth/login, yet You are posting to "url.com"

And small tip:

```
#instead of

zoektekst = str(zoek[0])
_token = zoektekst.replace("input"," ").replace("<"," ").replace("name="," ") \
  .replace("_token"," ").replace("type="," ")                                 \
  .replace("hidden","   ").replace("value="," ")                              \
  .replace("/>","").replace('"','').replace(' ','')

# use

zoektekst = zoek[0]["value"]
# now you can remove this insane amount of replace's
```

Comment: thanx, i have added the code ;) there isn't really a error message, if i load the page im just not logged in.... as i stated before im thinking the stuff that im putting into my request form is not complete, do you know where and especially what i have to put in the request? in the code i have included everything that i find in the form data after i logged in...

Comment: Using browser with developer tools enables to view post request before sending, this might be handy. Some servers use js tricks to for example include id of form. Is url of this page so secret You cannot write here, so anyone could check?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what is wrong since you've removed a lot of details, but assuming your `_token` is correct, I suspect your problem is:

```
r = requests.post("theurl.com",data=Payload)
```

needs to be

```
r = requests.post("theurl.com/auth/login",data=Payload)
```